# Extracting infromation from text using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to extract specific information from a long string text. The text is:

> Rating: Explicit Score: 17 Tags: apron blonde_hair brown_eyes itaru_chokusha kirigaya_kazuto long_hair nipples no_bra nopan nude sword_art_online yuuki_asuna User: openui

I want extract them as

1. Rating: Explicit
2. Score: 17
3. Tags: apron blonde_hair brown_eyes itaru_chokusha kirigaya_kazuto long_hair sword_art_online yuuki_asuna
4. User: openui

The code I tried could only take out the headers

```
$imageTitle = "Rating: Explicit Score: 17 Tags: apron blonde_hair brown_eyes itaru_chokusha kirigaya_kazuto long_hair nipples no_bra nopan nude sword_art_online yuuki_asuna User: openui";
preg_match_all("/[a-z]{1,}\:\s/i", $imageTitle, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

I tried using `(.*)` at last but it gave whole text. This one only extracts one word

```
preg_match_all("/[a-z]{1,}\:\s[a-z0-9]{1,}/i", $imageTitle, $matches);
//Output
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Rating: Explicit' (length=16)
      1 => string 'Score: 17' (length=9)
      2 => string 'Tags: apron' (length=11)
      3 => string 'User: openui' (length=12)
```

How to extract the remaining information? And also if possible as array index and  value too.

Comment: Before you can write a regular expression, you have to be able to describe, in English, the rules that you're trying to implement.  What you have said is an example of how the data should come out, but not an explanation of why.

Comment: @AndyLester, I want to process them to enter into database.

Answer (score 0):

This `preg_match_all` should work:

```
$s = 'Rating: Explicit Score: 17 Tags: apron blonde_hair brown_eyes itaru_chokusha
      kirigaya_kazuto long_hair sword_art_online yuuki_asuna User: openui';

if (preg_match_all('#\s*(.+?(?=((^|\s)[A-Z][a-z]*:\s*|$)))#i', $s, $arr))    
   print_r($arr[1]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Rating: Explicit
    [1] => Score: 17
    [2] => Tags: apron blonde_hair brown_eyes itaru_chokusha kirigaya_kazuto long_hair sword_art_online yuuki_asuna
    [3] => User: openui
)
```

Comment: I got `(\w+): ([^:]+)(?=$| \w+:)` work for this under Java at http://fiddle.re/r763a, but couldn't get it to work with php/preg_match. Any idea why?

Comment: BTW, I realize that I misread the question and broke out the key and values separately in the above, but still curious about preg_match not liking it .....

Comment: When I tried your fiddle, I got preg_match results of `Array
(
    [0] => Rating%3A+Explicit+Score%3A+17+Tags%3A+apron+blonde_hair+User%3A+openui
    [1] => Rating%3A+Explicit+Score%3A+17+Tags%3A+apron+blonde_hair+User%3A+openui
    [2] => 
)`

Comment: I know your ideone demo works. Turns out my regex works there too. Neither your regex nor my regex works on regexplanet, however, at least for me. See my earlier comment for the results I get from your fiddle. Do you get something different?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: The link I provided your for regexpal: http://fiddle.re/5gb3a does work

Comment: I gather you're seeing something different than I am, then. See https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20150157/Regex.png for what I'm seeing.

Comment: Please could you explain how the regex extracts the exact pattern. And why are four different array being outputted and why are you only selecting the second using `$arr[1]`?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: That is correct output. If you see `[1]` entry your will  see `Rating%3A`, `Score%3A` entries which is same as `Rating:`, `Score:` etc

Comment: @mrN: That is way `preg_match_all` works. You get full matched text in `[0]` position and your own groups # starting from `[1]` etc. See this official manual for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: @anubvha - Actually, no. If you look at the screenshot, you will see that [1] contains the entire target string, not what you indicated.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: Yes that is right its indeed the target string since it is output of `preg_match()` call. What I have above in my answer (and on ideone) is output of `preg_match_all()`. Those 2 functions operate differently.

Comment: @anubhava - I hate to keep belaboring this, but I really think there is an issue here with regexplanet. I'm familiar with the difference between `preg_match` and `preg_match_all`. But `preg_match` should not be matching the entire string with the regex you provided, as shown by http://ideone.com/skNWRS. Yet that is what is shown in the fiddle you published.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: I think you're right that regexplanet is showing full matched string in preg_match column which is **not exactly the output of preg_match**